# Alternative to nested ifelse() statements in R

Tags: r, if-statement

## Problem

I need a function which computes uncertainty of measurement by an instrument for different ranges (eg. I measure electrical current and if it's in the range of 2 mA the uncertainty is `0.1 % + 3 dig` of the measured value). It is better if the function is able to take a vector and return a vector instead of just numbers.

I have written the function with lots of `if`s but it returns warnings `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`. After a while of research I have discovered that `if`s in R are designed to work with an expression which evaluates to a single boolean value while `ifelse` can work with vectors.

But as there are about ten chained `else if`s the same thing with `ifelse`s would be rather ugly.

## Example

with `if`s:

```
S.I = function(I) {
   if(I<=(2*10^(-6))){
      0.1*I/100 + 3*10^(-9)
   } else if(I<=(20*10^(-6))) {
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

with `ifelse`s

```
S.I = function(I) {
   ifelse(I<=(2*10^(-6)),0.1*I/100 + 3*10^(-9),ifelse(I<=(2*10^(-6)),...,ifelse(...)))
}
```

## Question

Is there an alternative to `ifelse`s in this case?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: You don't have to complete an `ifelse` on the same line.

Comment: While you can't throw a vector into `S.I` as currently written, you can keep using the if-else paradigm if that is easier, and then use `Vectorize(S.I)` which you can pass vectors to

Comment: If you are wanting to choosing behaviour by splitting I into non-overlapping ranges, you might have some luck with `findInterval` and `switch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of doing this in `R` is probably `cut`; here's an example.

```
## some sample current values
I <- c(1e-6, 2e-6, 1e-5, 2e-5, 1e-4, 2e-4, 1e-3, 2e-3)
## define the endpoints for the different ranges
breaks <- c(-Inf, 2*10^(-6:3))
## for each range, define the percent of the original
## and the amount to add
percent <- c(0.10, 0.11, 0.12, 0.13)
dig <- c(3e-9, 3e-8, 3e-7, 3e-6) 
## get the range that each value falls in
range <- cut(I, breaks, labels=FALSE)
## and multiply by the right percent and add the right extra amount
I*percent[range]/100 + dig[range]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, your function only works with single values as `if` does not act on vectors. The solution is to send each value of your vector one by one to the function.

R provides a set of `apply` function to do exactly that (it's like a for loop but faster) :

```
result = sapply(I_vector, S.I)
```

If you want to apply `S.I` several times in your code on vectors, it can be worth using a wrapper :

```
wrapper_S.I = function(I) { return(sapply(I_vector, S.I)) }
result = wrapper_S.I(I_vector)
```

*NOTE:* You can also create the wrapper with `Vectorize`:

```
wrapper_S.I = Vectorize(S.I)
```

which creates a wrapper with extra controls.